# Ruby: Yaml::dump outputs integers in quotes using Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, yaml, dump

I am writing a Ruby gem that converts a sql executable to yaml, using Yaml::dump.  However, when testing it in Postgresql I am finding that the integers are output with single quotes around them (as strings) unless they start with a zero.  Below is the code snippet of the call to Yaml::dump and some resulting data.

```
db_object = {}
db_output = {}
full_table = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM #{model};")
keys = full_table[0].keys
db_object["columns"] = keys
model_arr=[]
full_table.each do |row|
  model_arr << row.values_at(*keys)
end
db_object["records"] = model_arr
db_output[model] = db_object
YAML::dump(db_output, file)
```

And here are the first couple rows of results:

```
schema_migrations:
  columns:
  - version
  records:
  - - '20121225230020'
  - - '20121225230129'
---
students:
  columns:
  - id
  - first_name
  - last_name
  - date_of_birth
  - rank
  - phone
  records:
  - - '1'
    - Celestino
    - Towne
    - '2007-09-20'
    - '2'
    - '6417358360'
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's because they *are* strings, everything you get back is a string, you have to handle the type conversions yourself. There are some methods that might help (check [the docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/frames)) or you could study how ActiveRecord does things. Everything will, of course, be database-specific. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a proper low-level and portable DBI for Ruby.

Comment: So I guess having an app agnostic yaml exporter isn't as easy as dumping it. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Right, it is a bit of a mess, I guess Ruby people are supposed to only talk to databases through ORMs. If you're assuming that you're in an ActiveRecord environment then you could ask the model class what the column types are; but if you're doing that then you might as well use the model classes and say `model_instance.attributes.to_yaml` together with `find_in_batches`.